# iPhone 6s Plus - video chat problem

Tags: iphone, facebook

Friend called me using Facebook Messenger. She could see me, but I was not able to see her (Everything else was perfect). There was a large, grey square area with a camera icon with a line through it.

I thought it was a tap-icon, so I could go find a setting I'd missed. But it would not respond.

I explored settings and found nothing to help. What am I missing please? Thank you.
Don

Answer (score 1):

The settings that control this are on her phone - not yours.